# Proving analyticity at a point by showing continuity

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

To show $\sqrt{z}$ is analytic on $\mathbb C-\{z \le 0\}$, Ahlfors shows that $w=\sqrt{z}$ is continuous on that domain. I don't understand what he means by saying once the continuity is established the analyticity follows by derivation of the inverse function $z=w^2$. What theorem do we use?

Comment: It follows from the inverse function theorem.

Comment: Since you know it is continuous and you know that the inverse is analytic, it follows that the function itself is analytic

Comment: @T.Bongers Using the inverse function theorem to show $\sqrt{z}$ is analytic, why do we show $\sqrt{z}$ instead of $w^2$ is continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a detailed argument: let $g(z)=z^{2}$ and $f$ be the given function. Then $\frac {g(f(z+h))-g(f(z)} z=\frac {z+h-z} h =1$. This can be written as $\frac {g(f(z+h))-g(f(z)} {{f(z+h)-f(z)}} \frac {f(z+h)-f(z)} h =1$. The first factor tends to $g'(f(z)$ by definition of derivative and the fact that $f(z+h)-f(z) \to 0$. It follows that $\frac {f(z+h)-f(z)} h$ has  a limit. [Note that the denominator $f(z+h)-f(z)$ does not vanish for $h$ near $0$ because $f(z+h)=f(z)$ implies $g(z+h)=g(z)]$ .

This argument is quite general. Note that $g'(f(z))\neq 0$ is also required and this is obviously true in our case.

Comment: If we use the inverse function theorem to show a function $f$ is analytic at a point, we not only need to show the inverse of $f$ is continuously differentiable but also need to show $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @user398843 Yes. In this case $f$ has a nice inverse on $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ but $f$ is not analytic there because it s not even continuous.

Comment: You need $g'(f(z)\neq 0$ and it is not a priori obvious that this holds.

Comment: @Matematleta Thanks for the comment. I have added a line to my answer. What is you need is indeed quite obvious here.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: should dot the i's and cross the t's though. (: Now I am happy to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to simply note that by restricting the domain of $f$ to $\mathbb C\smallsetminus \{z \le 0\}$, we have defined a (principal) branch cut for the complex logarithm, and now $\sqrt z:=e^{{1\over 2}Log z}$ is analytic, being the composition of two analytic functions.